# How to limit moveable areas of a window in Qt with using QMdiArea ?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to implement a project and in this project I will have different windows, so I want to give them a specified area that can move.

For example, a window will not be able to pass the half of the screen.

Is that possible to do this with sing QMdiArea ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMdiArea allows you to add windows to this area. Possibly stacking different windows on a QMdiArea. You can use different areas and add your subwindows to it. But that's actually for whole different purpose.

In order bring in your restriction on windows using [QMoveEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#moveEvent) of window would be more easy and good in this event oldpos() of the window can be used to and current pos() can be used to restrict your window movement, like if it reaches boundary and try to cross ,you have to constantly replace the position of your window to the limit on every QMoveEvent where current pos() is crossing the limit. You can also use setfixedheight(),setfixedwidth() if you want to.